# Spatial type Entity Framework Core SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to work with georaphic distances.

I got

```
public class Clinic
{
    ...
    public double Latitude
    public double Longitud
    ...
}
```

This clinics are on a SQL Server DB. I need to return them ordered by distance to a certain point. 
For what I read, Entity Framework Core has no support for DbGeography or something of that sort as to represent the SQL Server type:

```
geography
```

I added to the database a column with the calculated geography point of each clinic

```
UPDATE Clinics SET Geo = geography::Point(Clinics.Latitude, Clinics.Longitud,4326)
```

OK, know i need to return them ordered. SQL supports this by querying

```
DECLARE @p geography;
SET @p = geography::Point(41,2,4326);
SELECT * FROM Clinics c ORDER BY @p.STDistance(c.Geo);
```

and Entity Framework Core supports querying with a raw SQL.

```
context.Clinics.FromSql("..query..")
```

Thing is, as the documentation of the FromSql says, if the data you are returning doesn't exactly match the model it crashes.
As in C# I cant have a DbGeography that represents Geo I can't figure out how to resolve this.

**EDIT 1:**

Got it to partially work with the following:

```
string rawSQL = @"
        DECLARE @p geography;
        SET @p = geography::Point(41,2,4326);
        SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.Price, c.Quote, c.QuoteAuthor, c.QuoteSource, c.Description, c.Image, c.Latitude, c.Longitude, c.Category, c.CenterDistance, c.NumReviews, c.Stars
        FROM Clinics c
        ORDER BY @p.STDistance(c.Geo); ";
query = query.FromSql(rawSQL);
```

So now I get all the attributes of Clinics and it works! Thing is, clinics has a related class Amenities

```
public class Clinic
{
    ...
    public double Latitude
    public double Longitud
    public Amenity amenity
    ...
}
```

So when I run a query I need to include the amenities by linq

```
query = query.Include(c => c.ClinicAmenities).ThenInclude(ca => ca.Amenity);
```

Dies because Orderby from the raw sql comes before the include I believe

Comment: Did you figure this out? Did you get an error message when you "ThenIncluded" Amenity?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what error you get.

It seems to me you get error "The Include operation is not supported when calling a stored procedure."

What you could do is execute two queries.

Something like this

```
dbContext.Amenities.Load();

string rawSQL = @"
          DECLARE @p geography;
          SET @p = geography::Point(41,2,4326);
          SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.Price, c.Quote, c.QuoteAuthor
          FROM Clinics c
          ORDER BY @p.STDistance(c.Geo)";

// EF will automatically wire up the references between entities 
// that have been queried for
var clinicsWithAmenities = dbContext.Clinics.FromSql(rawSQL).ToList();
```